# Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade error on dual boot with Manjaro

Tags: grub2, kernel

I've been running Ubuntu 18.04 as a dual boot with Manjaro for the past few months without problems, but recently I get the following error message when I try to install upgrades:

```
linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic : Depends: linux-modules-4.15.0-20-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-4.15.0-22-generic : Depends: linux-modules-4.15.0-22-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

When I try to install the linux-modules packages on Synaptic, I get the following error:

```
Removing linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic (4.15.0-20.21) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: : Permission denied
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-4.15.0-22-generic (4.15.0-22.24) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-22-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: : Permission denied
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-22-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-22-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic
 linux-image-4.15.0-22-generic
libdvd-pkg: Package libdvdcss2-1.4.2-1 was removed, stop processing...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up grub-pc (2.02-2ubuntu8.2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-pc.config: 11: /etc/default/grub: : Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 installed grub-pc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic (4.15.0-29.31) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic (4.15.0-29.31) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: : Permission denied
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
 linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic
```

It seems (as far as I can tell?) like there's an issue with the grub. I installed grub with my Manjaro partition which would make sense why it's an issue for  Ubuntu.  Any suggestions what I can do? I'm fairly new to linux so would appreciate the help!